# How do you add items before and after a specific item in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I add an item in a list before a specific item within the list?

For example, if I enter 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 to create a list, how would I create a feature that allows me to add a number before a specific number and also a number after a specific number? I know I have to use index and insert, but I am unsure how to set them up.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Sample inputs and outputs, please.

Answer (score 0):

- to get the position of a value use `.index()`
- to add to a specific position use `.insert(idx, value)`

To add `before` use its index directly, to add `after` use the `index+1`

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 7]

# add a 4 before 5
values.insert(values.index(5), 4)
print(values)  # [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]

# add a 10 after 5
values.insert(values.index(5) + 1, 10)
print(values)  # [1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 7]
```

---

⚠️ **Caution** :be careful it there is **duplicates**, `.index()`  returns the `first` index of the value

Comment: It should be pointed out that this will behave funny if the elements are not unique

Answer (score 0):

That's how you would use `index/insert` to add values into a list, wrapped up in a function:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
def myInsert(lst, value, existingValue, after=False):
    if existingValue not in lst:
        print('Error: ExistingValue not found!')
        return
    
    currentPos = lst.index(existingValue)
    lst.insert(currentPos + 1 if after else currentPos, value)

myInsert(l, 99, 3, after=True)
myInsert(l, 101, 5)  # insert before!
print(l)
```

Out:

```
[1, 2, 3, 99, 4, 101, 5]
```

Note:
`index()` returns the first position of an item!